# Eigenvalues of adjoint, is this proof good?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Not asking for answers, just want to know if this argument is good.

> If $T$ is an operator on $V$ for $\dim V  < \infty$, then $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $T \iff \overline{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^*$.

Basically I said

\begin{align}
(v, T^*w) &= (Tv, w) \\
&=(\lambda v, w) \\
&=\lambda(v,w) \\
&=(v, \overline{\lambda}w)\\
\end{align}

Homogenity in the first and second slots are used.

**note**: the equivalence is given for any $v \in V$, so we can just take $v = 1.$

Comment: @carmichael561 yes.

Comment: The equality does not hold for any $v$ though, $v$ must be an eigenvector for $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. And in any case it's not clear what $v=1$ means.

Comment: @carmichael561 ah okay thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit more complicated. As we assume finite dimension then $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue of $T$ means $Z=\ker (T -\lambda I)$ is non-trivial. So if $v\in Z\setminus\{0\}$ we have for all $w\in V$:
$$ 0 = ((T-\lambda)v, w) = (v, (T^*-\bar{\lambda})w) $$
showing that the image of $T^*-\bar{\lambda}$ is orthogonal to $v$. In other
words the map is non-surjective. Since in finite dimension it must also be non-injective so $W=\ker(T^* -\bar{\lambda} I)$ is non-trivial. Whence $\bar{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^*$.

Comment: But what is wrong with mine? That was the question.

Comment: I don't think you can't conclude directly from your equality that $\bar{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue. You would have to take the difference between RHS and LHS and go through the argument with surjectivity and injectivity. Also in your argument $v$ should be an eigenvector of $T$ (not just $v=1$)

Comment: Looks like this technique is common and standard when considering eigen values and eigen vectors. It is nonsurjective because it contains a complement, if it were a surjective map on the whole space $V$, $V$ won't be able to decomposed into two irreducible spaces